# Anime about two girls who transport a loner kid from a classroom to a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime, isekai

There's also this alien they can ask a question every time they complete stuff for him. Like saving a village. Also another task is in the "real" current Japan. The boy gets a girl out of a bathroom where he thought she was being bullied, but was getting picked on for posting pic on her blog or something like that. Anime is definitely post 2000s.
This alien has half a head and talks in weird future slang, 'stand?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you first watch this? Also, can you describe the appearance of any of the characters, especially hair colour?

Comment: Is the "'stand" supposed to be you asking us, or an example of hus "future slang"?

Comment: So is the boy the "loner kid"? Is the girl in the bathroom one of the "two girls"?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[I'm Standing on a Million Lives](https://myanimelist.net/anime/41380/100-man_no_Inochi_no_Ue_ni_Ore_wa_Tatteiru)*. The manga version was identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212131). The anime aired from Oct 2, 2020 to Dec 18, 2020.

The man with half a head is the [Game Master](https://im-standing-on-a-million-lives.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Master). The wiki describes his speech pattern as

> He speaks in a strange fashion, only finishing half of the last word of every one of his sentences.

Which I believe could be taken as "future slang".

It's been a while since I read the manga, but rescuing a girl who was potentially being bullied sounds vaguely familiar.

The village would be Yuusuke's first quest; the game master assigns them tasks, and that was his. The two girls he was with had their own earlier quests, then recruited him. The girl in the bathroom was then recruited for their next quest; each quest in the fantasy world involves them recruiting someone new from the real world.